# My Ubuntu install keeps on crashing and I can't understand why

Tags: crash, 20.10

This is running on a ryzen 5 3500u.
that crashes are very in-frequent meaning this happens maybe once or twice a day

here is the output of "`journalctl -b -1 -e`"
https://pastebin.com/3zfjt6xE

and heres is the output of "`journalctl --since "2021-02-06 17:50:00`"
https://pastebin.com/W8q7XETB

Anything response or would be appreciated

Comment: What sort of activities is the computer doing when it crashes? Idling? Gaming? Compiling? I’m assuming this is an Ubuntu 20.10 Desktop installation and not one of the other common flavours …

Comment: yes, this is a ubuntu 20.10 desktop install. Normally im doing tasks like browsing the web, editing a file in vsCode or drawing things in gimp